# How to Redirect Slash at the end of my domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, slash

In my Google webmaster tools Google sees http://www.copperreflections.com/ separate from http://www.copperreflections.com How can I fix this this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't by redirecting/rewriting because as far as the server knows,`http://www.copperreflections.com/` and `http://www.copperreflections.com` are identical, the requested URI is `/` for both of them. You'll have to make sure that your pages use one with a trailing slash when linking to "copperreflections.com".

You may also be able to use javascript to redirect the browser when the address bar has the URL without the trailing slash to one with the trailing slash.